# How to fix gap in margin left and margin right qweb odoo

Tags: html, css, odoo, qweb

I want to add hr tag in sale quotation report template, but when I added hr tag, there is a little gap in left and right margin. That is not go to  the outline border.I try to set margin left and right to 0 in paperformat. But still gap ,how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try setting the paper-format?

Comment: You need to attach a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height and width for hr tag in an inline style to extend it to outline border. It works for me.

Try this :

```
<hr style="margin-left:-10%;margin-right:-10%;"/>
```